# MessageBox on worker thread

Tags: c#

My application has a worker thread doing some files synchronisation.

Under certain condition during the sync process, my worker thread needs to make a decision to continue or not.  Hence, I think I would ask for user feedback by showing a dialog box/message box.. (Yes/No).  Which would cause the worker to either continue or stop.

Now the question is:
Is it safe to show message box on non UI thread?
Would it possibly cause any potential issues?

Comment: The problem is not being able to set the proper parent:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949333/message-box-from-another-thread/13961697#13961697

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it safe to show message box on non UI thread ?

Yes it is safe. `MessageBox.Show()` is a static thread-safe method.

> would it possibly cause any potential issues ?

Not in this scenario I think. But you do block a Thread, not something you should do when you can prevent it.

Answer (score 3):

MessageBox is not tied to the UI. It is a simple Win32 API call. You can use it on any thread.

Comment: No. You can't. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121226/MessageBoxes-and-worker-threads