# Calling ShowDialog in BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a WinForms application in which my background worker is doing a sync task, adding new files, removing old ones etc.

In my background worker code I want to show a custom form to user telling him what will be deleted and what will be added if he continues, with YES/NO buttons to get his feedback.

I was wondering if it is ok to do something like this in background worker's doWork method?
If not, how should I do it?

Please advise..

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   MyForm f = new MyForm();
   f.FilesToAddDelete(..);
   DialogResult result = f.ShowDialog();
   if(No...)
   return;
   else
   //keep working...
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you try this you will see for yourself that it will not work because the `BackgroundWorker` thread is not [STA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute.aspx) (it comes from the [managed thread pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx)).

The essence of the matter is that you cannot show user interface from a worker thread¹, so you must work around it. You should pass a reference to a UI element of your application (the main form would be a good choice) and then use [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) to marshal a request for user interaction to your UI thread. A barebones example:

```
class MainForm
{

    // all other members here

    public bool AskForConfirmation()
    {
        var confirmationForm = new ConfirmationForm();
        return confirmationForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes;
    }
}
```

And the background worker would do this:

```
// I assume that mainForm has been passed somehow to BackgroundWorker
var result = (bool)mainForm.Invoke(mainForm.AskForConfirmation);
if (result) { ... }
```

---

¹ Technically, you cannot show user interface from a thread that is not STA. If you create a worker thread yourself you can choose to make it STA anyway, but if it comes from the thread pool there is no such possibility.

Comment: Thanks Jon I will try it out and see if it works for me.. Your answer has made sense..

Comment: By the way, someone told me elsewhere it is safe to call MessageBox.show(..) on BackgroundWorker perhaps because the method is statis.. is it also unsafe() ?

Comment: @Ahmed: That someone doesn't know what they are talking about. There is a related question here, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559252/does-messagebox-show-automatically-marshall-to-the-ui-thread. Conclusion: you *can* use it, but not because it's `static` or some other rubbish reason like that. It's because it specifically sets up its own message pump.

Comment: Thank you Jon, You are the real Guru :) Please check this post which I was referring to about MessageBox where it was reasonsed that it is static no message pump was pointed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283881/messagebox-on-worker-thread

Comment: @Ahmed: Well, that answer is indeed not phrased in the most technically accurate manner. I assume it came out like that because of imperfect communication between the person who wrote it (who undoubtedly knows *why* it works) and you.

Comment: Thanks Jon for being so helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

I usually create a method to execute a delegate on the UI thread:

```
  private void DoOnUIThread(MethodInvoker d) {
     if (this.InvokeRequired) { this.Invoke(d); } else { d(); }
  }
```

With this, you can change your code to:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   DialogResult result = DialogResult.No;
   DoOnUIThread(delegate() {
      MyForm f = new MyForm();
      f.FilesToAddDelete(..);
      result = f.ShowDialog();
   });

   if(No...)
   return;
   else
   //keep working...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IMO answers stating that you should launch a thread to handle this are misguided. What you need is to jump the window back to the main dispatcher thread.

#### In WPF

```
public ShellViewModel(
    [NotNull] IWindowManager windows, 
    [NotNull] IWindsorContainer container)
{
    if (windows == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("windows");
    if (container == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
    _windows = windows;
    _container = container;
    UIDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher; // not for WinForms
}

public Dispatcher UIDispatcher { get; private set; }
```

and then, when some event occurs on another thread (thread pool thread in this case):

```
public void Consume(ImageFound message)
{
    var model = _container.Resolve<ChoiceViewModel>();
    model.ForImage(message);
    UIDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _windows.ShowWindow(model)));
}
```

#### WinForms equivalent

Don't set UIDispatcher to anything, then you can do have:

```
public void Consume(ImageFound message)
{
    var model = _container.Resolve<ChoiceViewModel>();
    model.ForImage(message);
    this.Invoke( () => _windows.ShowWindow(model) );
}
```

#### DRYing it up for WPF:

Man, so much code...

```
public interface ThreadedViewModel
    : IConsumer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the UI-thread dispatcher
    /// </summary>
    Dispatcher UIDispatcher { get; }
}

public static class ThreadedViewModelEx
{
    public static void BeginInvoke([NotNull] this ThreadedViewModel viewModel, [NotNull] Action action)
    {
        if (viewModel == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("viewModel");
        if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
        if (viewModel.UIDispatcher.CheckAccess()) action();
        else viewModel.UIDispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
    }
}
```

and in the view model:

```
    public void Consume(ImageFound message)
    {
        var model = _container.Resolve<ChoiceViewModel>();
        model.ForImage(message);
        this.BeginInvoke(() => _windows.ShowWindow(model));
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Where are the answers that state another thread should be launched?

Comment: I never saw such an answer in response to my question .. may be someone created and removed it

Comment: All over the internet. I just had this problem myself today. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should bring up the dialog before you run the backgroundworker. And in the progresschanged-event, you can update the dialog.