# Thread disappearing?

Tags: c#

On a button click I start thread:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(TestThread);
myThread.IsBackground = true;
myThread.Start();
```

Inside thread method:

```
// Start stopwatch
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();


// Our method
HelperMethods.Mymethod(
    "19-04-2015",
    "20-04-2015",
    Properties.Settings.Default.username,
    Properties.Settings.Default.password
);


// stop it
watch.Stop();

// Get number of ellapsed milliseconds
var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;


TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(elapsedMs);
string answer = string.Format(
    "{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s:{3:D3}ms",
    t.Hours,
    t.Minutes,
    t.Seconds,
    t.Milliseconds
);


MessageBox.Show("Done " + answer);
```

I launched this thread yesterday and left my computer unattended (Windows+L).
Next day I was waiting to see above Message Box saying "Done".
But it was not there even though `Mymethod` *had* to terminate in that period.
Whole code inside `Mymethod` is inside `try/catch` and I log exception that
occurs inside that method. Strangely there was no exception logged
indicating that my program was terminated unexpectedly or something.
The last message logged (NB: I log only errors) was coming from previous day around 9PM.
After then, no sign ...
It is strange situation I am in... what can be happenning here?
Any ideas?
Sadly I terminated the application when came back without
being able to check if Mymethod was still running or not-but it should not have been running since it had more than enough time to finish for the time it was left operating.

Comment: Consider using a debugger and setting some breakpoints to determine where the actual behavior of your program differs from your expected behavior.  Go line by line if you have to.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov [It doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283881/messagebox-on-worker-thread) . It shouldn't either, if the owner of the message box is unspecified.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: This is mymethod is writing some data to database - there is indication the method didnt' finish because there is data missing in the database. So I guess something happened *before* message box

Comment: check the event log, uncatched exceptions which crash the app are logged there.

Comment: @PeteBaughman: I could but it will be difficult to trace - because that method works well when I test say with few input data. I set it with lot of data yesterday that is why it was left unattended.... (it is reading some data from files and adding to database - and like I said with small inputs it works well typically; actually it has worked ok with large inputs too before)

Comment: @MartinMoser: What is event log? btw the application didn't seem to crash the main dialog was there - just there was no message box

Comment: @user300244: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308427

Comment: You are saying that you log exceptions that happen in your `Mymethod`. Is that done with `catch(Exception ex)`? If you do not use `catch(Exception ex)` - there is a chance that you miss to catch some exception.

Comment: can't you just start it again and when you come back in the morning and it shows no message just click 'pause' in your IDE?

Comment: @SteffenWinkler: Never used that pause but now I am building using CTRL+F5 so pause won't be option I think - but I added logging locally what app is doing at given time (not logging just errors anymore). But I still want to find out what happened at that point... ?

Comment: @MartinMoser: Any hints how to find "interesting" logs in there?

Comment: When you came back next day - was your machine simply locked or in Sleep Mode?

Comment: @FAngel: Good question but how can I tell - actually the screen was black but it was also locked I had to log in

Comment: If it is in sleep mode - it is usually silent (fans not working) and it takes some seconds to start. If it is simply locked, but not sleeping - it should be noisy as usual and the only thing happens when you move your mouse - screen is turned on.

Comment: @FAngel: hard to say that but screen was black-and I had to log in

Comment: See if your Windows has enabled sleep mode. And how much time it will wait before going into sleep. If sleep is enabled - most likely that is the problem. It is easy to find in google where that option is located

Comment: And besides, when you do you database writes - do you have some column with time when row was created?

Comment: @FAngel: You mean column which says at what time some row was inserted? No. (but like I said I added local logging now to check when I am back if app is still running)

Comment: @FAngel: Finding now how to check if that sleep mode is enabled

Comment: @MattBurland:But my app was not crashed as suggested by martin

Answer (score 0):

`MessageBox.Show()` should be invoked on the UI thread and not from a background thread. May I suggest using a `Task` with a continuation:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(TestThread);
task.ContinueWith(parent => 
{
    if(parent.Exception != null)
        MessageBox.Show("Done.");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Exception occurred.");
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

The above will start your method on another thread and when the method will complete, it will schedule the lambda from `ContinueWith()` to be executed on the UI thread. This way, the call to `MessageBox.Show()` won't break your application.

Of course, don't forget to remove the call to `MessageBox.Show()` from the `TestThread` method.

Comment: I am bit new to C# so would be nice if I could find the error without Task factory etc since I am not familiar with them. PS. There is reasonable doubt the problem occured before message box

Comment: @user300244, can you post the whole code? Maybe I can help debugging.

Comment: Please look here: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:4fbe; I don't want to post it here, hence the link (I will remove it some time later)

Comment: @user300244, that method should write something in the log files. Have you tried running it in debugger?

Comment: Like I said that method works ok if I don't ask it to process many files - so that is why I thought there was no need to debug. ps the log files had nothing interesting like I said

Comment: It worked ok even with many files last time just now I encountered this strange situation

Comment: I would appreciate if you can help and spot smth in that method- I provided you with the source :)

Comment: @user300244, the first thing that pops in mind is that you're working with file system and that is prone to errors - do you have access to those files, are all the paths correct, are those files locked etc? However, those problems should be logged with `AppendToLogFile`. All I can suggest is putting a breakpoint at the beginning of `TestThread` and debug the application.

Comment: Thanks but like I said method works correctly (outputs ocrrect data to database) for small inputs hence I thought I could find nothing weird during debug

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Windows is configured to go to sleep or even hibernate when there is no input from user for a long time (by default - around 15-30 minutes, I guess).

Taking into account that it was left for a whole night, it could go to sleep and stop all processes. So, basically thread was running for a while, but later it has been paused because of machine going to sleep mode. And it was not working the remaining time. When you came back - thread resumed, but application is turned off shortly. In other words, machine was not working most time and thread had not time to run to the end.  And turning app off you just stopped it completely.

Below is replacement for your `HelperMethods.Mymethod`, it is executed in a separate background thread, just like in your case:

```
while(i < 1000) { 
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now); 
    i++; 
    Thread.Sleep(1000); 
}
```

When I run it and turn machine to sleep - this is output I'm getting.

```
4/21/2015 6:00:45 PM
4/21/2015 6:00:46 PM
4/21/2015 6:00:47 PM
4/21/2015 6:00:48 PM
*** gap here. machine is in sleep, thread not working ***
4/21/2015 6:01:02 PM
4/21/2015 6:01:03 PM
4/21/2015 6:01:04 PM
```

Besides, calling your methods `Mymethod` is a bad idea. Method name should be descriptive. It should be easy to understand what it is doing without looking into it.

Comment: :Thank you-of course method has another name(I even posted its code in commends below to an answer). Thanks for your suggestion I will explore it - but thing is I have left this computer unattended even for longer period of time using this same software - and I didn't observe such problem last time... that is why I got confused this time

Comment: So I have to ensure my computer doesn't Sleep? I found this setting and I am not sure if this is the right one: http://postimg.org/image/7up1ako09/ ?

Comment: Oops. Sorry) I've looked at methods code, but paid no attention to how method is called there. On that Sleep option - looks like the right place. And Hibernate set to never should turn it off.

Comment: Yes but that Hibernate was already set to never  - that is why I am confused? Actually some items above there was option set: Turn Hard Disk off After 20 minutes - could that cause the problem?

Comment: but strangely I have left it like this for longer period and it seemed to work ok

Comment: Hm... any chance of some lock related to DB? Or some deadlocks because of another thread?

Comment: not sure about locks and deadlocks- where to check that? What do you think about turn off hardware option like i mentioned above?

Comment: Hardware should not be a problem. It goes down only if no access to it. And your app should be using hard drive periodically. That will not allow it to turn off. About locks - do you use other threads in your app? If yes - do they share some data (access same object/variable)? When you work with database - are there any asynchronous operations? Do they access same tables for read and write?

Comment: You mean about:"Turn Hard Disk off After 20 minutes"? About threads no that myMethod (you can also refer to its code) is the only thing running and it periodically writes data to different tables of database; I don't recall using asynchronous methods

Comment: Yes, I mean "Turn Hard Disk off After 20 minutes" option. Yes, I saw your method code and methods like `Logs.Log1(currentTerminalName, currentDate);` are suspects for new threads. But if there are no threads in them - I have no more ideas. The best here would be to log every operation and see when it stops. Maybe, that will help somehow

Comment: Do you have any idea if it is possible to find out whether computer was in sleep mode in some given time?

Answer (score -1):

MessageBox.Show("Done " + answer); It crashes, and that causes your thread to disappear. You should move the call to MessageBox.Show outside the thread. Call it when the thread has finished.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show` is legal to use cross thread if the owner of the message box is unspecified.

Comment: This is what i'm saying too! It crashes because of the cross thread and the link contains an article that explains how to manage this.

Comment: @RadinGospodinov: So you say problem is because of message box? Like I said with high likelihood problem occurred (if it occurred at all) before because there was some data missing in the database too